# putting `nload` output into a file

Tags: command-line, network-monitoring, traffic

I want to generate a simple report of total network usage into a text file.(amount of total used traffic)
I searched a bit and I found `nload` software, but when I write this command in the terminal:

```
nload > x.txt
```

the command line gets stuck and does not end until I hit ^C.
I know this is because the nload updates itself every moment,

but is there any method to just get the first output of the nload and put it in the file?

Comment: You can save the output for for eg. 10 secs with `timeout 10 nload | tee nloadlog.txt`, but `nload` is a TUI program. You might want to find a modern alternative that collect and just show a summary at the end. [Here a bunch to test](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/). Maybe [`speedtest --csv --secure >> myspeedlog.csv`](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/)?

Comment: thank you @PabloBianchi . I also just found where the nload gets its data and now I can read that file. it is `/proc/net/dev`

Comment: That's another different question, and first you should specify the specific interface to analyze. To get a summary after x seconds you could try `vnstat`, `ifstat`, `dstat` and `collectl`.

Answer (score 0):

`nload` is an interactive console program that, unfortunately, is not designed to get easily an snapshot of the current status in the first iteration (like the `top` command, that has the `-bn 1` option to do that). We could automate the waiting and the stopping after 5 seconds like this:

```
nload > nload.log 2>&1 & (sleep 5 ; killall nload)
```

but in that case `nload.log` will include the ANSI codes used by `nload` to position the data in the console, impeding a simple visualization of the file data without resorting to extensive cleaning of the file unwanted characters.

Other similar tool for visualizing transfer rates, `iftop`, has the `-t` (text output mode) option to send tabulated data to the standard output channel without control codes, so it could be called like this:

```
iftop -nNbp > iftop.log 2>&1 & (sleep 5; killall iftop)
```

And this information, (of several iterations during the indicated 5 sec interval) can be read with `cat iftop.log` or `less iftop.log` commands.
The options `-nNbp` disable name/port resolution and bar graphs, and enable promiscuous mode -- check `man iftop`.

Of course, there are other tools maybe better oriented to analyzing the behaviour of the network usage, i.e., `sysstat` (as indicated by [Pablo Bianchi](https://askubuntu.com/users/349837/pablo-bianchi)'s comments in the question).

On the other hand, some terminal programs can capture console text by simply selecting it with the mouse. After that, you could open a text editor, paste the copied text and saving, obtaining that way a report in a file WITHOUT the invisible control codes for positioning data.